# How can I compare a users input to a list of methods?

Tags: c#

I'm writing some code where I have made a few methods and have put all of them in a list however I want the user to be able to choose a method from the list and then run that method as i dont want all the methods to run and only output the answer of chosen method as this is inefficient.

```
class program
    {
        //arrays
        static void Arrays()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of cars:");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // List
        static void List()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter items for shopping list");
            shoppingList.Add("Apples");
            shoppingList.Add("oranges");
            shoppingList.Add("milk");
            shoppingList.Add("butter");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Main(string[] strings)
        {
            List<Action> methods = new List<Action>();

            methods.Add(Arrays);
            methods.Add(List);

            Console.WriteLine("what method do you want:");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (Action a in methods.Where(//one of the methods == answer));
                Console.WriteLine(//the method that is == answer);

            if (answer == //one methods in list)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(////the method that is == answer);   
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post what you have at the moment in a code block? It is hard for me to imagine

Comment: create a dictionary with the names (strings) as keys and the functions/delegates as values. Alternatively you could use an enumeration as index into an array and map the strings to the enum.

Comment: i just wanted to create a program where the user can choose what methods they want to run  at the moment theres only 2 and they will do seperate things they not very important  and method that is euqal to the answer means that it will run the method is the user chooses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> methods = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
methods.Add(nameof(Arrays), Arrays);
methods.Add(nameof(List), List);

Console.WriteLine("what method do you want:");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if(methods.TryGetValue(answer, out Action doIt))
{
    doIt();
}
```

Comment: @Coder175 Never mind a friendly comment but the canonical way to say "thank you, that helped" is to upvote and accept (click on the check mark)  the answer.